# C# StreamReader ReadLine() hangs on second attempt, unless threads exit

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, tcpclient, streamreader

I have inherited the code below, from another developer, which makes requests to an external system.

I call the GenerateRequest method using different values for the 'method' parameter (from a BackgroundWorker) all of which work fine. When I then make a second call it still works for all but one of the 'method' values (which also contains different values for the 'parameters' value, I'll include the calls too below), which hangs on the StreamReader ReadLine() call. However, if I debug and step through the code allowing 10-20 seconds, the output shows a few 'The thread 0xd0f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0)' messages and the code then works.

I feel I have an issue with the thread from which I'm doing this work, but I can't figure it out, please help.

This works everytime;

```
   ClientParameters parameters = new ClientParameters();
   string request = requestHandler.GenerateRequest("GetFunctions", parameters);
```

This only works the first time, unless I debug and step through, allowing time for threads to exit.

```
ClientParameters parameters = new ClientParameters();
        parameters.Filter = new ClientParametersFilter();
        parameters.Filter.Demographics = "";
        parameters.Filter.Medication = "";
        parameters.Filter.MinEffectiveDate = DateTime.Now;
        parameters.Filter.MaxEffectiveDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
        string request = null;
        try
        {
            request = requestHandler.GenerateRequest("GetRecord", parameters);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // log error
            return null;
        }
```

Hear is the class for making requests;

```
public class MyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler{
public string GenerateRequest(string method, ClientParameters parameters)
{
    ClientIntegrationRequest request = new ClientIntegrationRequest();
    request.APIKey = ApplicationSettings.APIKey;
    request.Function = method;
    request.FunctionVersion = 1.0M;
    request.RequestUID = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    request.DeviceID = ApplicationSettings.DeviceId;
    request.DeviceVersion = ApplicationSettings.DeviceVersion;
    request.FunctionParameters = parameters;

    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClientIntegrationRequest));
    string xml;
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ser.Serialize(m, request);
        // reset to 0
        m.Position = 0;
        xml = new StreamReader(m).ReadToEnd();
    }

    try
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", ApplicationSettings.Port);
        NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        if (netStream.CanWrite)
        {
            xml = xml + "\n";
            Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
            netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            netStream.Flush();
        }
        else
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            netStream.Close();
            return null;
        }
        netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        if (netStream.CanRead)
        {
            StreamReader l_textReader = new StreamReader(netStream);
            string str = l_textReader.ReadLine(); // Here's the issue
            l_textReader.Close();           
            tcpClient.Close();
            netStream.Close();
            return str.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            netStream.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        // log error
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // log error
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look the Microsoft example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.7.2
you can view that the code read the client stream by low level code reading the content returned by a byte array:

```
if (netStream.CanRead)
{
    // Reads NetworkStream into a byte buffer.
    byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

    // Read can return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead. 
    // This method blocks until at least one byte is read.
    netStream.Read (bytes, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

    // Returns the data received from the host to the console.
    string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (bytes);

    Console.WriteLine ("This is what the host returned to you: " + returndata);

}
```

Can you try this reading method?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I have already attempted this method. I've just tried it again to make sure and I get the same result, the code now hangs on the NetworkStream Read() method on the second call.

Comment: In the article: "Call the Read method to receive data arriving from the remote host. Both of these methods block until the specified operation is performed. You can avoid blocking on a read operation by checking the DataAvailable property. A true value means that data has arrived from the remote host and is available for reading. In this case, Read is guaranteed to complete immediately. If the remote host has shutdown its connection, Read will immediately return with zero bytes. ". Can you try to test the DataAvailable property before read?

Comment: When I call netStream.DataAvailable before Read(), it just equals false every time, even on the calls which don't hang on Read(). No use :(